# Using org.apache.commons.mail.Email with org.apache.camel.Exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I have configured my smtp-listener via Apache camel which provides exchange object which support `javax.mail` API but I want to use exchange object with `org.apache.commons.mail` library

Something like this

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    
    String result = null;
    String resultJson = null;
    
    Email message1 = exchange.getIn().getBody(org.apache.commons.mail.Email.class);
    
    MimeMessageParser mimeMessageParser = new MimeMessageParser(message1);
    mimeMessageParser.getHtmlContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly a [Camel Mail](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mail-component.html) listener gives you as message body, but I guess it is the raw message body.

Your code on the other hand shows a Java class that implements the [Processor interface of Camel](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/processor.html). You need to register this class in the Camel registry (or as a Spring Bean if you use Spring).

Therefore you can call your processor code in the Camel route when a mail is coming in:

```
from("imap://admin@mymailserver.com?password=...")
    .process(myEmailProcessor)
```

The type you receive in the message body is obviously not `org.apache.commons.mail.Email` but a type of `javax.mail` (perhaps `MimeMessage`?).

So you should be able to use `MimeMessageParser` to parse the incoming message and from there use the Apache Commons Email library.

Comment: yes I tried using MimeMessageParser  it it gives me null value

Comment: .javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage message = exchange.getIn().getBody(javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.class);
  
  
  MimeMessageParser mimeMessageParser = new MimeMessageParser(message);
  mimeMessageParser.getHtmlContent();

Comment: Debug into your processor and check if the type you get from `exchange.getIn().getBody()` really is  `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`. If it is, I suspect missing Camel stream caching being responsible for the `null` body.

Comment: So does it work when you use this type? `javax.mail.Message message = exchange.getIn().getBody(javax.mail.Message.class);`